# Equivalent of a wildcard in find for batch?

Tags: batch, search, find, string, findstr

I'm almost certain this is a duplicate but I was unable to find it after a lot of searching so forgive me. 
    I'm looking for a way to have the equivalent of a wildcard in the find command. For instance, If I want to find a line in a file that has `09/(some unknown string here)/2018` How would I go about doing this? I'm open to using the `findstr` command too.

Comment: Have you tried actual wildcards (% *)?

Comment: Yes it just searched for them. I hadnt tried with findstr though and it needs a period too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findstr` supports some simple regular expressions - see the bottom of the output of `findstr /?`. To match any run of characters, use `.*`. The dot matches any single character, and the asterisk allows matching the previous character (any character, in this case) any number of times. So this will find any lines that contain `09/` and `/2018` with any characters in between:

```
findstr "09/.*/2018" MYFILE.TXT
```

If you only want to match lines where the unknown string is exactly two characters long (since your search string appears to be a date), just use two single-character wildcards:

```
findstr "09/../2018" MYFILE.TXT
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I searched Super User before posting this answer and was also unable to find a straight answer for you.

Comment: This isnt working actually, it seems  it works without the `.*` example: `findstr "09/ /2018"`... I dont understand findstr at all :D

Comment: @MarkDodsons That's interesting; the `.*` method seems to be working for me. May I see an example of a line that isn't found when it should be?

Comment: I figured it out, it does not work with /C: that was my problem

Comment: @MarkDodsons - It does work with `/c:regexSearch` if you also use the `/r` option. `/c:` defaults to literal search, but can be overridden with `/r`.